# Google Maps Geolocation api : access not configured

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to use google geolocation api on Android. I am sure I have valid apikey for android and I have enabled billing.
However, the server returns

doman: usageLimits
reson: access not configured
code : 403

Could anyone solve this problem?
PS: I don't have an enterprise support for google map development. My code is listed below

```
JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();  
JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();  
JSONArray wifiarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject cell = new JSONObject();
JSONObject wifi1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject wifi2 = new JSONObject();
try {
    cell.put("cellId", cid);
    cell.put("locationAreaCode", lac); 
    cell.put("mobileCountryCode", mcc);  
    cell.put("mobileNetworkCode", mnc);
    cell.put("age", 0);
    cell.put("signalStrength", -95);
    cellarray.put(cell);

    wifi1.put("macAddress", "01:23:45:67:89:AB");
    wifi1.put("signalStrength", 8);
    wifi1.put("age", 0);
    wifi1.put("signalToNoiseRatio", -65);
    wifi1.put("channel", 8);
    wifiarray.put(wifi1);

    wifi2.put("macAddress", "01:23:45:67:89:AC");
    wifi2.put("signalStrength", 4);
    wifi2.put("age", 0);
    wifiarray.put(wifi2);

    holder.put("homeMobileCountryCode", mcc);
    holder.put("homeMobileNetworkCode", mnc);
    holder.put("radioType", "gsm");
    holder.put("carrier", "T-Mobile");
    holder.put("cellTowers", cellarray);
    holder.put("wifiAccessPoints", wifiarray);


} catch (JSONException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key="+API_key);
StringEntity stringEntity = null;  

try {  
    stringEntity = new StringEntity(holder.toString());  
    stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");

    Log.v("zf",stringEntity.getContentType().toString());

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}

httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);  
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;  
try {
    httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);  
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: try adding sensor param to end of your url

Comment: In this example, the Geocoding API requests a json response for a query on "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA":

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
We've left the sensor parameter in this example as a variable true_or_false to emphasize that you must set this value to either true or false explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason #1: Add the sensor value to your url, it is NOT optional!

Possible reason #2: Have you enabled the Geolocation service in your API console?

Possible reason #3: Have you setup your billing information in your API console?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is clear when you read the string response:

```
"code": 403,
"message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
```

Go to the Developers Console and under Credentials add your app under "Restrict usage to your Android apps".